# Does Firebase Firestore count reads of the same document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As I understand, when we call `get()` on some reference, Firebase gets lastest snapshot of this document from Firestore.

So my question is:
If at the beginning of app (for example in some init) I call something like `firestore.collection(food).doc(pizza).get().data()` and it gives me some Snapshot of this document where I get data.

Lets say, later in app, I call the same reference `firestore.collection(food).doc(pizza).get().data()` in some side effect of completely different method and read this data again. Before this, the document didn't change.

Will Firebase count this as one or two reads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `get()` will obtain a new snapshot of the document, as long as there is internet connectivity.  If the app is offline, the SDK will attempt to use the local cache instead.

If you want to understand in more detail about how the cache works, [read this blog post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/firestore-clients-to-cache-or-not-to-cache-or-both-8f66a239c329).

Comment: Thanks for response. But it’s still unclear for me - will firebase count it as two „reads” in billing? I know get() return new snapshot, but if this snap is the same like previous one, will it be counted as another read in billing?

Comment: For each get() that goes to the server, it's counted as a read.